# Как получить часть ссылки после "?" в Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Из

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/category?area=&city=&price=&rating=asc
```

вот эту часть:

```
?area=&city=&price=&rating=asc
```

Comment: Как насчет стандартний функции из документации https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.parse-url.php ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$url = explode('?', $url);
$url = '?'.$url[1];
```

Answer (score 4):

В Laravel это можно сделать так:

```php
$query = request()->query();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#retrieving-input-from-the-query-string